# C# SuperSocket without protocol

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, system.net.sockets, supersocket.net

The question is simple: I've read the whole [SuperSocket](http://www.supersocket.net/) documentation but I don't understand if there is a way to use it without implement a protocol.

I don't need to send specific commands but only bytes which might be one or hundreds, depending by many factors. I need to renew an old TCP server that uses simple sockets, it was made by me using System.Net.Sockets libs more than 4 years ago and I'd like to realize a stronger solution using a well note library as SuperSocket is.

Is it a good idea?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what do you mean without implement a protocol? Super Socket will either use TCP or UDP depending on the configuration

Comment: Well, obviously it uses TCP and UDP as transport level protocol. But reading documentation it seems that you need to develop a communication protocol to encapsulate data.
If you take a look [here](http://docs.supersocket.net/v1-6/en-US/The-Built-in-Command-Line-Protocol) you can read what I mean. The first question in the page has exactly the answer to your one. I read _You need to define your application level protocol..._, this seems mandatory.
Thank you.

Comment: Do you just want to receive the data as Bytes?

Comment: Yes, my need is to send two independent streams: one up and one down, not commands. As you could do with a serial port. Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't have to implement a protocol, you can simply create a `ReceiveFilter` by implementing the interface: `IReceiveFilter`.

So first create a custom RequestInfo class like the one below:

```
public class MyRequestInfo : IRequestInfo
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Unicode { get; set; }

    // You can add more properties here
}
```

Then create the ReceiveFilter - the ReceiveFilter is basically the class which filters all incoming messages. This is what you need if you don't want to implement a protocol.

```
public class MyReceiveFilter: IReceiveFilter<MyRequestInfo>
{

// This Method (Filter) is called whenever there is a new request from a connection/session 
//- This sample method will convert the incomming Byte Array to Unicode string

    public MyRequestInfo Filter(byte[] readBuffer, int offset, int length, bool toBeCopied, out int rest)
    {
        rest = 0;

        try
        {
            var dataUnicode = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(readBuffer, offset, length);
            var deviceRequest = new MyRequestInfo { Unicode = dataUnicode };
            return deviceRequest;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int LeftBufferSize { get; }
    public IReceiveFilter<MyRequestInfo> NextReceiveFilter { get; }
    public FilterState State { get; }
}
```

Next Step is to create a custom `AppSession`. Session is like when a client connects the server creates a session for it, and is destroyed when the client disconnects or when the server closes the connection. This is good for situations when you need the client to connect and then the server has to send ACKnowledgment for the client to send the next message.

```
public class MyAppSession : AppSession<MyAppSession, MyRequestInfo>
{
    // Properties related to your session.

    public int ClientKey { get; set; }

    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }

}
```

And the Final Step is to create your custom `AppServer`

```
// Here you will be telling the AppServer to use MyAppSession as the default AppSession class and the MyRequestInfo as the defualt RequestInfo

public class MyAppServer : AppServer<MyAppSession, MyRequestInfo>
{
// Here in constructor telling to use MyReceiveFilter and MyRequestInfo

    protected MyAppServer() : base(new DefaultReceiveFilterFactory<MyReceiveFilter, MyRequestInfo>())
    {
        NewRequestReceived += ProcessNewMessage;
    }

    // This method/event will fire whenever a new message is received from the client/session
    // After passing through the filter
    // the requestInfo will contain the Unicode string
    private void ProcessNewMessage(MyAppSession session, MyRequestInfo requestinfo)
    {
        session.ClientKey = SessionCount;

        // Here you can access the Unicode strings that where generated in the MyReceiveFilter.Filter() Method.

        Console.WriteLine(requestinfo.Unicode );

        // Do whatever you want

        session.Send("Hello World");


        session.Close();
    }
}
```

You can also override other methods of the AppServer class like:  `OnSessionClosed` or `OnNewSessionConnected`

That's it - then you just have to initialise and start the server:

```
            var myAppServer = new MyAppServer();

            if (!myAppServer.Setup(2012))
            {
                _logger.LogMessage(MessageType.Error, string.Format("Failed to setup server"));
                return;
            }
            if (!myAppServer.Start())
            {
                _logger.LogMessage(MessageType.Error, string.Format("Failed to start server"));
                return;
            }
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try.
[edit] I'm sorry but I can't upvote your answer because my reputation is not high enough. :(
I will do it in future, when I will can. I promise.

Comment: As I promised, after more than 1 year... I can upvote your answer! ;)