# AppServer.NewRequestReceived event doesn't fire in SuperSocket

Tags: c#, supersocket.net

I've created a server that just prints out a line whenever a new request is received:

```
var server = new AppServer();
if (!server.Setup(2012) || !server.Start()) {
    return;
}
server.NewSessionConnected += (session) => Console.WriteLine("new connection");
server.NewRequestReceived += (session, requestInfo) => Console.WriteLine("new request");
```

I connect to it from netcat:

```
C:\Users\sashoalm>nc localhost 2012
test
test
^C
C:\Users\sashoalm>
```

It prints `new connection` but never prints `new request`, despite typing 2 lines from netcat. I know that netcat sends the text to the server each time a full line has been typed (that's how netcat works).

**Edit:** I found another (not very well worded) unanswered question that might be asking the same thing - [How to send data to server using supersocket library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32815027/how-to-send-data-to-server-using-supersocket-library), but I'm not entirely sure if it's the same problem. The guy there tries to send data from code it seems.

Another related question - [C# SuperSocket without protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38051152/c-sharp-supersocket-without-protocol). They talk about protocols there. Is there a default protocol in SuperSocket when you don't specify one? Is it HTTP or something else?

Comment: It prints both `new connection` and `new request` by using **telnet localhost 2012**.

Comment: @jstreet You're right. It works with telnet but not with netcat. I don't understand what the difference would be. Maybe it requires \r\n line endings and netcat uses only \n, I don't know.

Comment: If you build a simple client and send a list of strings, some with `\r\n` and some without it, you will see the difference: the strings in the list that do not have `\r\n` are concatenated with the next one that does have it, forming one single request.

Comment: @jstreet You are correct, I tested it with a simple Qt program and it works exactly as you described. I assume it's because HTTP uses `\r\n`, and SuperSocket is based on HTTP maybe, not just TCP. If you post your comments as an answer I'll accept it and award the bounty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a simple client below, based on this [MSDN Sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb5kfec7(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve("localhost");
        IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
        IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 2012);

        Socket sender = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        sender.Connect(remoteEP);

        Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}", sender.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

        List<string> list = new List<string>
            {
                "Test1\r\n",
                "Test2",
                "Test3\r\n",
                "Test4\r\n",
                "Test5\r\n",
                "Test6\r\n",
                "Test7",
                "Test8\r\n",
                "Test9\r\n",
            };

        foreach (string s in list)
            sender.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s));

        sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        sender.Close();
    }
```

and using a slightly modified version of your server:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var server = new AppServer();

        if (!server.Setup(2012) || !server.Start())
        {
            return;
        }

        server.NewSessionConnected += (session) => Console.WriteLine("new connection");
        server.NewRequestReceived += (session, requestInfo) => Console.WriteLine("new request: Key={0}", requestInfo.Key);

        Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to exit....");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

shows the effect of using or not `\r\n` as terminator for a request:

> ```
> Press ENTER to exit.... 
> new connection 
> new request: Key=Test1 
> new request: Key=Test2Test3 
> new request: Key=Test4 
> new request: Key=Test5
> new request: Key=Test6 
> new request: Key=Test7Test8 
> new request: Key=Test9
> ```

Requests without a terminator are concatenated with the next one until the terminator is found.